# How to add spring plugin in 'intelli J'?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, intellij-idea

I cannot able to find spring in my listed plugins..and also i am not able to find spring-boot in marketplace..I am trying to learn spring, but getting lot of obstacles like this.can someone please help me in this?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the Community Edition? Spring plugin is only available in the Ultimate edition.

Comment: If you need Ultimate license for free, see the page for students: https://www.jetbrains.com/community/education/

Answer (score 0):

Frameworks support for spring is available in IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate only. You can see the details on the [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html).

[image]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Ultimate edition, spring is already included in it.